# Getting this footer to appear in the centre in the same position on all resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I have this css, now it looks like a want it to in my 1366x768 laptop screen, it appears at the centre of the screen at the bottom. But when I move it to my larger screen, the footer appears in a different position, further up the page.

Can anyone give me some suggestions please?

```
position:relative;  
width:900px;
height:70px;
background-color:#0CF;
margin-top:38%;
right:25%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-450px;
```

Comment: try to target `position` from `bottom` instead of `margin-top`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why:

```
margin-top:38%;
```

38% of any different screen height will result in a different position for your footer, assuming it is position relative to the body and not to another element that may have another position. In your case I would be willing to bet it is relative to the body.

If you change that to position absolute, then give it a bottom value it will stick to the bottom of the screen.

```
position:absolute;  
width:900px;
height:70px;
background-color:#0CF;
bottom:0;
right:25%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-450px;
```

Comment: Ah ok, so is there a better way of positioning in a way that I want it to look then?

Comment: I updated, though this could vary depending on your html and your actual intentions

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
position: absolute;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

with the width that you already have, that should centre it. Then

```
bottom: 0;
```

should put it at the bottom of the screen. Then you can get rid of `left`, `right`, `margin-top`.

[edit] The finished thing would look like this

```
position: absolute;  
width: 900px;
height: 70px;
background-color: #0CF;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Ah ok, it is now in the same position at the bottom of the screen, but is not centred? I removed the margin-left references and anything to do with that. Should I have done that?

Comment: I'll post the whole CSS from your example